# R: Create panel dataset from time series variables

Tags: r, regression, panel-data

I have a dataset that has the following form:

```
Year ... X1   X2 ... XN ... Y1 Y2 ... Y5 ...
2006 ... 
2007
...
2016
```

where I run separate regressions for each of the Y's as dependent variables and the X's as the independent variables.

I would like to transform this dataset into a panel dataset so I can run fixed effects panel regressions.

Any idea how I can transform my dataset into the desired format?

I post a part of my dataset in case it helps:

```
structure(list(Year = c(2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 
2013, 2014, 2015, 2016), X1 = c(NA, 6231989.16, 
6286192.8, 7997940.88, 5964272.33, 2220471.25, 1161886.38, 1854724.67, 
7414435.45, 1030764.86, 1760876.07), X2 = c(NA, 
16033423.97, 14591392.59, 10807666.03, 10568403.25, 9895997.3, 
7783115.74, 9609331.42, 13195226.51, 9840290.11, 10612093.19), 
Y2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 26041118.06, 
    18038215.91, 19174941.38, 15250404.65, 19670622.34, 19969051.53, 
    13454512.28, 17033742.37), 
    Y1 = c(NA, 51860962.74, 38081542.65, 24057388.46, 24340687.5, 
    27960591.55, 25526505.72, 31599623.65, 38597641.61, 48611516.44, 
    45851933.17), Y3 = c(NA, 30898514.64, 34234806.16, 
    38595099.38, 41654402.22, 41895856.36, 45906588.53, 58857032.54, 
    68599527.69, 69905755.6, 63085613.98
)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000004601ef0>, sorted = "Year")
```

Comment: Your data frame contains a time column/variable (`Year`). But I don't see any column dedicated to individuals. To create a panel dataset you need both, see [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plm/versions/1.6-5/topics/plm.data)

Comment: Yes I don't have a unique identifier for my data. But I run separate regressions for each of the Y's. I was thinking if I could somehow run this with panel data fixed effects...

Comment: A fixed effects panel regression refers to a regression model in which the group (firms, states, etc.) means are fixed (non-random). If you cannot clearly identify the groups, you cannot use a fixed effect model

Comment: I have 5 Ys (dependent variables). I could use each of them as one group, meaning having 5 groups in total..

Comment: Yes, it's an option. Does this imply that you also have 5 `X` per row (one for each Y) ?

Comment: No I use different X's for the different Y's, so I thought I could somehow transform it into some panel data format... Let me know if you have any ideas/suggestions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189078/discussion-between-ang-and-adrcoder).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a two-step solution. Be aware that you end up with the same `Xs` for all the groups.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plm)
# 1- from 3 Ys to 3 groups
df.panel <- df %>% 
        gather(group, Y, -year, -starts_with("X")) %>%
        arrange(year)
glimpse(df.panel) # have a look at df.panel
# 2- clean group ID by removing the first character ("Y")
df.panel$group <- substr(df.panel$group, 2, nchar(df.panel$group))
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(year = 2006:2016, X1 = c(NA, 6231989.16, 6286192.8, 
7997940.88, 5964272.33, 2220471.25, 1161886.38, 1854724.67, 7414435.45, 
1030764.86, 1760876.07), X2 = c(NA, 16033423.97, 14591392.59, 
10807666.03, 10568403.25, 9895997.3, 7783115.74, 9609331.42, 
13195226.51, 9840290.11, 10612093.19), Y2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 26041118.06, 
18038215.91, 19174941.38, 15250404.65, 19670622.34, 19969051.53, 
13454512.28, 17033742.37), Y1 = c(NA, 51860962.74, 38081542.65, 
24057388.46, 24340687.5, 27960591.55, 25526505.72, 31599623.65, 
38597641.61, 48611516.44, 45851933.17), Y3 = c(NA, 30898514.64, 
34234806.16, 38595099.38, 41654402.22, 41895856.36, 45906588.53, 
58857032.54, 68599527.69, 69905755.6, 63085613.98)), .Names = c("year", 
"X1", "X2", "Y2", "Y1", "Y3"), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems like you are selecting the variables based on how their name starts ("X"). Is there a way to do it by using different names (e.g. instead of Y I have variables called Group_2_1, Group_2_2 or even different names e.g. bananas) and instead of Xs I have other name variables e.g. Interest_Rate, Unemployment etc... How should I change your code in order to use other names for my variables?

Comment: Sure. You can use something like `gather(group, Y, -year, -Group_2_1, -Group_2_2 , -bananas)` but this is not very efficient. Also, note that it doesn't really make sense to have the same Xs for all individuals in panel data

Comment: My initial dataset has 11 rows, running this code: `library(tidyverse)
library(plm)
# 1- from 3 Ys to 3 groups
df.panel <- df%>% 
        gather(group, Dependent_1, Dependent_2, Dependent_3, Dependent_4, Dependent_5, -Year) %>%
        arrange(Year)
glimpse(df.panel) # have a look at df.panel` creates a dataset with 44 variables, while 55 should be in the final dataset. Some dependent  variables do not appear in the final dataset. Why is this happening? Sorry I don't know these at all so I might be doing sth stupid here!

Comment: Try with `gather(group, -Dependent_1, -Dependent_2, ...)`

Comment: How can I use different independent variables for different dependent variables? E.g. I would like to keep `X1, X2, X3 for Y1`, and `X4, X5, X6 for Y2`, and so on.. Some variables might be the same while some might be different.